# How to access a method in a viewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, callback

I have the following scenario.

In my ZoomViewController

```
- (void) animationPicker: (NSString*) type;
```

and I want to access it in my IntroViewController using the following code..

```
ZoomViewController *zoomvc = [[ZoomViewController alloc] init];
[zoomvc animationPicker: @"Fade-in"]
```

but this is not working.. Why? and What is the solution?

[image]

Comment: It looks fine.. what isn't working?

Comment: Where are you using this code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you create a new instance of the `ZoomViewController`, which gets discarded as soon as you are done with it. You are calling the `animationPicker:` method on the instance that is disconnected from the controller that is in control of the zoom screen.

The solution depends on the way that your communicating controllers are connected to each other. For example, if you bring up `ZoomViewController` using a *segue*, you can access the destination controller inside `prepareForSegue` method. Here is [an answer explaining how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11267780/335858).